# FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(fileSearch, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) isnt returning files that exist in the directory

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, fileinfo

I have the following FileInfo search pattern and files that are in the directory are not being returned.

```
        string fileSearch = itemP + "_" + ParseColor(itemC) + "*_c1.jpg";
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(fileSearch, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

File that exists in the directory is as follows:
            122929977_NAVY_HOHHE_0_0_c1.jpg

If i change the pattern to forget the color and the *_c1 it finds the file, but thats not what i need, there are images that have mulitple views of the picture, but the only one i need and want is the one that matches the color passed in and that has the _c1 in the name..

The pattern that is built and passed into the dir.GetFiles is "122929977_NAVY*_c1.jpg"

What am i doing wrong with this? Can it work with the expected pattern i want to pass?

Comment: Is the value of `fileSearch` actually `"122929977_NAVY*_c1.jpg"`? I just tested that pattern and it does find "122929977_NAVY_HOHHE_0_0_c1.jpg"

Comment: could it be that there is a case sensitivity issue? Or the extension is not jpg, but jpeg? I would take a very close look on your actual file name here

Comment: Also, is this file located on this `dir` directory, not a subfolder underneath? Just check if you can find anything with `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 yes, minus the quotes, thats what i see being passed in the variable filesearch when i debug and step thru the code.      In the directory, there are no subdirectories and there are 2 files that exist for the first part of the search pattern     122929977_NAVY_HOHHE_0_0_c1.jpg  and 122929977_NAVY_HOHHE_0_0_c2.jpg, in this case it should have found the _c1 file for me but never does..    Like i said if i change my pattern to just 122929977_NAVY*.jpg it works, but it returns the 2 files above and i only need the c1 image.

Comment: `dir` is DirectoryInfo object. Can you show how you built the Path used in the class constructor? Because, if the file name + wildcard is `"122929977_NAVY*_c1.jpg"` and the path is correct, you'ld have a result.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong, but you could try to work around the issue by using different way of filtering:

```
var files = dir.GetFiles(itemP + "_" + ParseColor(itemC), SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("_c1.jpg"))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Everyone i want to apologize for this post, after further testing and debugging i found that 2 methods prior to this method, my variable was changed, so the working path for the dir.getfiles was looking for files in the directory that they dont exist in yet. I just tested and so far seems to be working..